# Create a list of coordinates given a list of x values and a function

Tags: syntax

I have a function and $x$-values as a list. How do I construct a list with coordinates $(x_i,y(x_i))$, $i=1, 2, …$

```
y[x_]:= 2x
x = { -3, 0, 4, 5}
```

which should be made into

```
{ {-3,-6}, {0,0}, {4,8}, {5,10} }
```

Is there some compact command for this?
The following works but is perhaps not optimal;

```
Table[{x[[i]], y[x][[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[x]}]
```

Comment: For example `Table[{x, y[x]}, {x, xvalues}]` where `xvalues = {-3, 0, 4, 5}`. This is probably the most semantically appealing option. Another solution is `Transpose[{x, y /@ x}]` where `x` is as you defined it. Those are general solutions, in your case you have a listable function, which means that you can also use the slightly simpler `Transpose[{x, y[x]}]`, and if performance matters then this is what you should use.

Comment: Very nice. I agree that the `Table` variant is the most semantically appealing option but the others worked equally well.

Answer (score 4):

**Description**

In essence, the solution below employs a pure function.
The `{#, 2#}` defines the form of a sub-list structure where `#` is a slot. We then use a map `/@` to take each element from the list `{-3, 0, 4, 5}` and plug it into the slot to generate the desired output.

**Input**

```
{#, 2 #} & /@ {-3, 0, 4, 5}
```

**Output**

```
{{-3, -6}, {0, 0}, {4, 8}, {5, 10}}
```

**Reference**

[Pure Functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#17469)
[Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)
[Slot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)

Comment: This is, in addition to C.E.'s suggestions above is also a very 'neat' syntax, with the slight modification of `{#, y[#]} & /@ x`